# Inheritance: Access to base class fields from a subclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

How sub class objects can reference the super class?  For example:

```
public class ParentClass {

    public ParentClass() {}     // No-arg constructor.

    protected String strField;
    private int intField;
    private byte byteField;
} 


public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{

    // It should have the parent fields.
}
```

Here when the `ChildClass` constructor is called, an object of type `ParentClass` is created, right?

ChildClass inherits `strField` from the ParentClass object, so it (`ChildClass` object) should have access to `ParentClass` object somehow, but how?

Comment: This is really bad title. Consider putting some context there.

Comment: i agree,(:-) now it's better!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do `ChildClass childClassInstance = new ChildClass()` only one new object is created.

You can see the `ChildClass` as an object defined by:

- fields from `ChildClass` + fields from `ParentClass`.

So the field `strField` is part of ChildClass and can be accessed through `childClassInstance.strField`

So your assumption that

> when the `ChildClass` constructor is called, an object of type `ParentClass` is created

is not exactly right. The created `ChildClass` instance is ALSO a `ParentClass` instance, and it is the same object.

Answer (score 5):

An instance of `ChildClass` does not have a `ParentClass` object, it **is** a `ParentClass` object. As a child class, it has access to public and protected attributes/methods in its parent class. So here `ChildClass` has access to `strField`, but not `intField` and `byteField` because they are private.

You can use it without any specific syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `strField` just as if it is declared in `ChildClass`. To avoid confusion you may add a `super.strField` meaning you are accessing the field in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to access the `strField` form the `ChildClass`, without performing any special action (note however that only one instance will be created. The child, which will inherit all properties and methods from the parent).

Answer (score 1):

> here when the ChildClass constructor is called an object of type
>   ParentClass is created, right?

No! ChildClass constructor is called >> parent class constr is called 
and No Object of the ParentClass is created just accessible field from the parent class are inherited in ChildClass

> the ChildClass inherits strField from the ParentClass OBJECT, so it
>   (ChildClass object) should have access to ParentClass object somehow,
>   but how?

No, it is just a reusing the template of ParentClass to creating new ChildClass

Answer (score 0):

By focusing on the business of non-arg constructor and compiler's involvement only, while the derived class(`ChildClass`)'s default constructor(non-arg constructor) is being invoked, a subobject of base class(`ParentClass`) is created through the mechanism of compiler's help(insert base class constructor calls in the derived class) and wrapped within the derived class's object.

```
class Parent{
    String str = "i_am_parent";
    int i = 1;
    Parent(){System.out.println("Parent()");}
}
class Child extends Parent{
    String str = "i_am_child";
    int i = 2;
    Child(){System.out.println("Child()");}
    void info(){
        System.out.println("Child: [String:" + str + 
                           ", Int: " + i+ "]"); 
        System.out.println("Parent: [String: ]" + super.str + 
                           ", Int: " + super.i + "]"); 
    }
    String getParentString(){ return super.str;}
    int getParentInt(){ return super.i;}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Child child = new Child();
        System.out.println("object && subojbect");
        child.info();
        System.out.println("subojbect read access");
        System.out.println(child.getParentString());
        System.out.println(child.getParentInt());

    }
}
```

result:

```
Parent()
Child()
object && subojbect
Child: [String:i_am_child, Int: 2]
Parent: [String: ]i_am_parent, Int: 1]
subojbect read access
i_am_parent
1
```