# Why variable which didn't exactly declare equals to 0?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Please sorry me for that newbie question. This is for my so strange, because before java coding, I have had a C++ background, where variable by default is equal to `undefined` or `null`; 
So I have a `abstract class`:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    int lifeBar;
    public void eat(int x) {
        lifeBar += x;
    }
}
```

And I have **Bird** `class` which extends it:

```
public class Bird extends Animal {

}
```

And **Main** `class`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal bird = new Bird();
        bird.eat(10);
        System.out.println("bird: " + bird.lifeBar);
    }
}
```

I thought that there should be compilation error, because I didn't declare `lifeBar` variable, but the console showed me **10**. Why is that? Is it because there some default constructor?

Comment: It's right in your question tags. Inheritance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance: Access to base class fields from a subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452480/inheritance-access-to-base-class-fields-from-a-subclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lifeBar` is member of  `Animal` which isn't initialized explicitly, so it sets its default value that is `0` for `int`

**See**

- [default value of different types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

- Inheritance means subclasses can extends the state of superclass
- hence in your example, when `Bird extends Animal` all the methods and
  variables are inherited in `Bird` class.
- `lifeBar` is an instance variable of type `int` hence its default value is `0`
- YOu are calling the method in which `lifeBar += x;` statement increments the value by `10` because you are passing `10` as argument to method.

Comment: it is clear. But why it is equal to 0? not undefined?

Comment: @Beezy Instance variables that aren't explicitly set in the constructor/initialization blocks have a default value of 0/0.0/`'\u0000'` for primitives or `null` for reference types

Comment: @Beezy java specification says the default value of int variable should be 0 when it is an instance or static variable. If it were local, then you have to specify the value explcictly.